# Jenkins/Jetty returns "HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found"

Tags: jenkins

For a few days now our Jenkins server is returning "HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found" from jetty. The interesting behavior is, if I reload the page a couple of times (5-20 times) then suddenly the Jenkins UI appears, but on the next click it is "HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found" again. Jenkins runs in a container on k3s. The Jenkins logs do not show any issues, the java process does not crash. I tried the latest Jenkins version and a few older ones (all alpine-based). Until last week it has been working for several months without problems. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was the Traefik ingress configuration. I did use

```
- path: /jenkins
```

which worked fine for many months, after a reboot it did not anymore. When I changed it to

```
- path: /
```

it worked again. I do not understand why the behavior of traefik changed, but if someone runs into the same issue, maybe this post helps.